# How to replace update SQL query to CodeIgniter ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I use the CodeIgniter framework. I have a problem, when I try to update database using Active Record.
I found out how to resolve it via raw SQL.

```
UPDATE articles_articlegroups
  SET isDeleted = 1
    WHERE articlegroupId IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM articlegroups
      WHERE parent_id = $catID
      )
```

But I need use AR.

I nave category and subcategory with articles. Category and subcategory are in one table. Linked with `parent_id.`
Articles links are in one to many table, because its can belong to different categories.

Would like to delete all articles, know just `parent_id.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
 'isDeleted' => 1
 );
 $this->db->set($data); 
 $this->db->where(
    'articlegroupId IN (
                       SELECT id
                        FROM articlegroups
                        WHERE parent_id = '.$catID.'
                       )'
                   );\
 $this->db->update('articles_articlegroups');
```

Comment: Thanks, I read documentation and found out solution with sub-query. select()...->get_compiled_select() and where_in();

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

An easiest and quick way would be to do it via `$db->query("sql")`

```
  $sql= "UPDATE articles_articlegroups
  SET isDeleted = 1
  WHERE articlegroupId IN (
                          SELECT id
                          FROM articlegroups
                          WHERE parent_id = $catID
                          )";
  $this->db->query($sql);
```

but don't pass the parameter directly to avoid sql injection, bind the params in the sql string.

Comment: The variable should be replaced with a placeholder. `$this->db->query(" ... ( ... WHERE parent_id = ?)", [$catId]);`

Comment: @mickmackusa correct, that's why I mentioned some details about sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this,

```
$this->db->query("your query here");
```

Final query

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE articles_articlegroups
      SET isDeleted = 1
      WHERE articlegroupId IN (
                              SELECT id
                              FROM articlegroups
                              WHERE parent_id = $catID
                              )");
```

Comment: Yes I did it. But I need replace it with $this->db->update()

Comment: `$this->db->query()` will execute your update query. `$this->db->update()` is not necessary when you are usiong, `$this->db->query()`

Comment: Ok. But how I can use $this->db->where(), $this->db->update(), $this->db->set() and other methods ?

Comment: no need to use all those AR. When you are using `->query()`, pass plain query as parameter. CI will automatically execute the query.

Comment: The variable should be replaced with a placeholder. `$this->db->query(" ... ( ... WHERE parent_id = ?)", [$catId]);`